# MySQL transaction and triggers

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures, triggers

Hey guys, here is one I am not able to figure out. We have a table in database, where PHP inserts records. I created a trigger to compute a value to be inserted as well. The computed value should be unique. However it happens from time to time that I have exact same number for few rows in the table. The number is combination of year, month and day and a number of the order for that day. I thought that single operation of insert is atomic and table is locked while transaction is in progress. I need the computed value to be unique...The server is version 5.0.88. Server is Linux CentOS 5 with dual core processor.

Here is the trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER bi_order_data BEFORE INSERT ON order_data
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
  SET NEW.auth_code = get_auth_code();
END;
```

Corresponding routine looks like this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION `get_auth_code`() RETURNS bigint(20)
BEGIN
    DECLARE my_auth_code, acode BIGINT;
    SELECT MAX(d.auth_code) INTO my_auth_code
        FROM orders_data d
        JOIN orders o ON (o.order_id = d.order_id)
        WHERE DATE(NOW()) = DATE(o.date);

    IF my_auth_code IS NULL THEN
        SET acode = ((DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), "%y%m%d")) + 100000) * 10000 + 1;
    ELSE
        SET acode = my_auth_code + 1;
    END IF;
    RETURN acode;
END
```

Comment: Why don't you include the time down to ms. Or take a sequence/auto-increment number and add it on.

Comment: I second the auto-increment number, if you don't use some kind of internal method for counters, you will have the risk of a race condition

Comment: Well... Each row has a unique autoincrement no. However the counted number is used for other purposes. The order is entered into the table then fine state machine picks it up and sends it to be processed by legacy system. The order in table is then changed status as it progresses through the fine state machine. The legacy system supports 10 digit number in format described. So adding autoincrement would halt the system after 9999 orders total...

Comment: ZaQ is right. As long as you don't rely on a system wide auto-increment/sequence (sorry, I'm used to Oracle terms) you will always end up in race trouble with this procedure. I'm not terribly familiar with MySQL but it should be possible to obtain the next number from some sort of system wide sequence provider instead of adding one in the code.

Comment: A single statement is atomic, but that refers to actual queries. A stored proc is not an atomic operation - it's a series of individually atomic operations. You need a transaction and some locks in there to guarantee you get a unique MAX(d.auth_code)

Answer (score 2):

> I thought that single operation of
>   insert is atomic and table is locked
>   while transaction is in progress

Either table is locked (MyISAM is used) or records may be locked (InnoDB is used), not both.

Since you mentioned "transaction", I assume that InnoDB is in use.
One of InnoDB advantages is absence of table locks, so nothing will prevent many triggers' bodies to be executed simultaneously and produce the same result.